# Integration API with and parametric URI, laravel or not

Tags: laravel, api, integration

I want to consume a service like this

```
https://server.com/api/plate-number/{{plate_value}}/assistance
```

where plate_value is a dynamic variable.

I think i will do a form to consume this service and handle Json response.

Can i do with laravel and guzzle? Or is too much work for this?
Thx a lot

Comment: Did one of our answers solve your problem? if so please accept one of them.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use Http to make your request:

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
    $plate_value="your value";
    $response = Http::get("https://server.com/api/plate-number/$plate_value/assistance");
    dd($response->json());
```

[laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client#making-requests)

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple with Laravels `Http` facade. Concatenate the string, by using "" string literals and set plate value in your URL and the rest is just utilizing the facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$plateValue = 42;

$response = Http::get("https://server.com/api/plate-number/$plateValue/assistance");

// Get JSON
$result = $response->json();

// Get string
$result = $response->body();
```

For this to work you need guzzle installed.

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Comment: Yes, but that is an industry standard :)